# Parsing with Happy: left-recursion versus right-recursion

Tags: parsing, haskell, happy

[Section 2.2 of the Happy user manual](https://www.haskell.org/happy/doc/html/sec-sequences.html) advises to you use left recursion rather than right recursion, because right recursion is "inefficient". Basically they're saying that if you try to parse a long sequence of items, right recursion will overflow the parse stack, whereas left recursion uses constant stack. The canonical example given is

```
items : item            { $1 : [] }
      | items "," item  { $3 : $1 }
```

Unfortunately, this means that the list of items comes out backwards.

Now it's easy enough to apply `reverse` at the end (although maddeningly annoying that you have to do this *everywhere the parser is called*, rather than once where it's *defined*). However, if the list of items is large, surely `reverse` is *also* going to overflow the Haskell stack? No?

Basically, how do I make it so that I can parse arbitrarily-large files and still get the results out in the correct order?

Comment: Why would `reverse` use the stack? You can reverse a list in constant memory.

Comment: You can always use a different data structure like a [`Data.Sequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Sequence.html).

Comment: shouldn't the last item be | items "," item  { $3 : $1 } ? That is what the manual seems to be saying?

Comment: btw - I think the example should be ` | items "," item { ... }`

Comment: You could always have "items1 : items { reverse $1}". Then you can use "items1" every time.

Comment: @PaulJohnson Thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: @melpomene Given that reversing a list works by pushing all the list items onto the call stack and then pulling them off again in reverse order, I'm not sure how you do that in constant memory...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Haskell doesn't have a call stack, and that's not how reverse works. But I just noticed that my comment doesn't make sense: You use linear memory (for the reversed list itself).

Comment: `reverse xs = aux xs []`
`aux [] ys = ys`
`aux (x:xs) ys = aux xs (x:ys)`
Doesn't use any stack. Only tailcalls.

Comment: @svenningsson Also known as `foldl (flip (:)) []`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is the entire `items` to be `reverse`d every time, you can define

```
items  : items_           {reverse $1}

items_ : item             { $1 : [] }
       | items_ "," item  { $3 : $1 }
```

`reverse` won't overflow the stack. If you need to convince yourself of this, try evaluating `length $ reverse [1..10000000]`

Comment: I still haven't wrapped my mind around how reverse manages this task, but it clearly *does*, and that's the important bit.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid, it's all on the heap, not the stack. These days, though, the stack isn't fixed in size anyway.